# Flutter Could Not Find Correct Provider with Speedometer

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-widget

This is my widget build.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final providerData = Provider.of<SpeedometerProvider>(context);
providerData.getSpeedUpdates();
```

This is my provider

```
class SpeedometerProvider with ChangeNotifier {
Speedometer _speedometer =
  new Speedometer(currentSpeed: 0);

Speedometer get speedometer => _speedometer;
Stopwatch _stopwatch = Stopwatch();
final Geolocator _geolocator = Geolocator();

....
```

and this is my screen

```
SafeArea(

            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Padding(

                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        right: 200.0, top: 550.0),
                    child: Center(
                        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                          Text("Anlık HIZ",
                              style: Theme
                                  .of(context)
                                  .textTheme
                                  .bodyText1),
                          SevenSegmentDisplay(
                              value:
                              '${providerData.speedometer.currentSpeed
                                  .toStringAsFixed(0)}',
                              size: 4,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                              segmentStyle: HexSegmentStyle(
                                  enabledColor: Colors.green,
                                  disabledColor: Colors.white)),

                          Text("Kmh", style: Theme
                              .of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .bodyText1)

                        ])),
```

and this is the error:
Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this MapView Widget

This likely happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:

- The provider you are trying to read is in a different route.

  Providers are "scoped". So if you insert of provider inside a route, then
  other routes will not be able to access that provider.
- You used a `BuildContext` that is an ancestor of the provider you are trying to read.

Answer (score 0):

Before using the provided value inside your `build()` method, you should create and provide it to your widget tree first:

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
  create: (_) => SpeedometerProvider(),
  child: ...
)
```

You can provide it at the root level or based on your example, you can just simply wrap your `SafeArea` widget with it.

Also, considering your example:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final providerData = Provider.of<SpeedometerProvider>(context);
providerData.getSpeedUpdates();
```

You should not load data inside the build method - if this load takes some time, your UI would be freezed until the data is loaded. Use something like `FutureBuilder` to handle it, but that's a different topic.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i have a question. Where can I write instead of writing in building? Because I have to define. I could not find another place. I'm very new to flutter.

Comment: Not sure, that depends on your app structure, state management and so on. If you need to load that data only once, the simplest solution would be to use StatefulWidget and do that inside initState.